# Need a list of Pcap.Net members or classes?

Tags: vb.net, pcap.net

Need a list of Pcap.Net members or classes? Their website doesn't have much documentation and have looked around in the forums.

I have found..

`PacketTs = Packet.Timestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff")

PacketS = Packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Source

PacketSp = Packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Transport.SourcePort

PacketD = Packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Destination

PacketDp = Packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Transport.DestinationPort

PacketP = Packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Protocol`

What other data can be extracted. Like the IpV6 info etc..
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have their library referenced by your project, you can view all the namespaces, classes, and class members defined by that library in the object browser.  In Visual Studio, select the Object Browser option from the View menu.